# pdo prepared statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, pdo

I'm making the switch from mysql_connect to pdo and can't get it going. here's my code:

```
//get the row sk
$sk = strtok($string, "_");
//get the column name (the rest of the $string)
$column_name = substr($string, strpos($string, "_") + 1);
//get the value
$value = $_SESSION['save_arr'][$string];
echo "{$column_name} {$value} {$sk}</br>";
$sql = "update tbl_brand set ?=? where brand_sk=?";
$q = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($column_name, $value, $sk));
```

if I hard code some values in then it works fine

```
$sql = "update tbl_brand set name_long='name' where brand_sk='1'";
```

I'm sure it's just a  syntax problem but I just can't see it. I'm working off this example http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Error-Handling-P552.html

the results from the echo are like so:

name_long National Autjho Glass 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

column names can't be bound to dynamic values in a prepared statement. only constants like strings and integers can be bound. so, your sql should contain the column name before it's prepared:

```
$sql = "update tbl_brand set `$column` = ? where brand_sk = ?";
```

you'll want to make sure the $column value is sanitized properly before embedding it in the sql statement.

in mysql, you can escape the column identifier like so:

```
$column = str_replace("`", "``", $column);
```

Comment: you're a lifesaver man :) I thought it'd be something silly like that... I'll select as best answer in 5 mins when it'll let me